# writing a query to get the value of a certain shortcode as on today,30 days back and 60 days back in a single select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table Revenue_shares table and I need to write a query to get the value of a certain shortcode as on today,30 days back and 60 days back in a single select.Tried subquery but it's not working

```
select shortcode,Name,Value today_value,
       (select Value from Revenue_shares 
        where convert(date,[Date]) = (convert(date,getdate()-30)),
              (select Value from Revenue_shares where convert(date,[Date])=(convert(date,getdate()-60))
from Revenue_shares
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: "it's not working" - in what way? Incorrect results? Error messages? Caused server to spontaneously combust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this - maybe the easiest would be to use joins (inner if your sure the shortcode/date record will exist, left outer if not)

```
select today.shortcode, today.value todayvalue, lastmonth.value lastmonthvalue, twomonths.value twomonthsvalue
    from revenue_shares today
    inner join revenue_shares lastmonth on lastmonth.shortcode=today.shortcode 
        and [date]=dateadd(day, -30, getdate())
    inner join revenue_shares twomonths on twomonthsshortcode=today.shortcode 
        and [date]=dateadd(day, -60, getdate())
     where today.[date]=getdate()
```

Or something similar at least.

Comment: Outer joins would be better. What if there was no data for 60 days ago?

Comment: Agreed - which is why i said : "(inner if your sure the shortcode/date record will exist, left outer if not)"

Answer (score 1):

You have more opening parentheses than closing.
And you don't need subqueries, you need `JOIN`s here.
Assuming, `shortcode` is unique id, the following should work:

```
SELECT r1.shortcode,
       r2.Name,
       r1.Value today_value,
       r2.Value 30daysago_value,
       r3.Value 60daysago_value,
  FROM Revenue_shares r1
       INNER JOIN Revenue_shares r2
                  ON r1.shortcode = r2.shortcode
       INNER JOIN Revenue_shares r3
                  ON r2.shortcode = r3.shortcode
 WHERE     convert(date,r1.[Date]) = (convert(date,getdate()))
       AND convert(date,r2.[Date]) = (convert(date,getdate()-30))
       AND convert(date,r3.[Date]) = (convert(date,getdate()-60))
```

Also, next time use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to check the parentheses.